# Binding data to jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-dialog

I have an `asp:datalist` bound to a database. When the user clicks a button on one of the rows, a dialog needs to be shown where the user is prompted to enter additional information.

This dialog needs some information from the item clicked. For this, I'm trying to look at `Jquery Dialog` and `Jquery.data()`. I don't know, if this is possible at all. The dialog shows up fine, but the data is not passed.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                var minattend = $(this).data('minattend')
                var maxattend = $(this).data('maxattend')

                DoAdditionalSearch(minattend , maxattend);
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And the ItemDataBound in code-behind:

```
LinkButton lnkBook = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lnkBook"), LinkButton);
lnkBook.OnClientClick += "$('#dialog-confirm').data('minattend', " + countmin + ");";
lnkBook.OnClientClick += "$('#dialog-confirm').data('maxattend', " + countmax + ");";
lnkBook.OnClientClick += "$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); return false;";
```

When I run the code, the `minattend` and `maxattend` is undefined

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the generated HTML to see if there is anything in the generated links `onclick` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops. Was passing strings, and missed a couple of "'":

> lnkBook.OnClientClick += "$('#dialog-confirm').data('minattend',
>   **'**" + countmin + "**'**);"; lnkBook.OnClientClick += "$('#dialog-confirm').data('maxattend', **'**" + countmax + "**'**);";

And now it works like a charm. Glad I learned this :)